# Time delay variables applied in wrong order in setTimeout loop

Tags: jquery, variables, delay, settimeout

(Novice here) I have a setTimeout loop with a variable of time delay values. It cycle's through a ul, adds a class to a list item, after a predetermined amount of time it removes that class and jump to the next list item; repeating the process until it has reached the last (li)

The problem is that the time delay values are being applied incorrectly. The last time delay value is being applied to the second-to-last list item instead of the last.

http://jsfiddle.net/bizarroZ/YyDjW/

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
li {display:none;} .go {color:green;display:block}
</style>

<ul>
<li>First Slide</li>
<li>Second Slide</li>
<li>Third Slide</li>
<li>Fourth Slide</li>
<li>Fifth Slide</li>
<li>Sixth Slide</li>
</ul>

<a href="#" class="go-button">GO!</a>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(".go-button").click(function() {

     $("li:nth-of-type(1)").addClass("go"); 

    var index = 0;
    var length = $("ul").children().length;
    var delays = [
            1000,
            1500,
            2000,
            2500,
            3000,
            15000

    ];

    function delayNext()
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
        $("ul li:eq(" + index +  ")").addClass("go").siblings().removeClass("go");
            index++;

            if (index == length)
                index = 0;

            delayNext();
        }, delays[index]);
    }

    delayNext();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YyDjW/19/)
... not a good solution though but it does what you intend to do...

**problem in your code**
on click event you are adding the class `go` to the first child that is *first slide* and on `setTimeout` you are again assigning class `go` to *first slide*  `:eq` selector follows a *zero based  indexing* so by the time you reach the 5th slide your counter is set to 15000 milliseconds i.e the time after `delayNext()` is called again

Comment: @3nigma - That doesnt seem to work its still doing the same thing. If you click the go link on the jfiddle result panel you'll see that The last time delay value is being applied to the second-to-last list-item, instead of the last list-item. http://jsfiddle.net/YyDjW/16/

Comment: @3nigma - sorry for the confusion, thank you for you effort - what I mean is that I need the sixth slide to hold for 15 seconds

Comment: @3nigma - Beautiful! Works perfectly, thank you for taking the time to help me out.